# How to stick fixed div of height more than viewport to body

Tags: jquery, css, html

I know about the positioning of div (fixed, absolute and relative). I can attach a fixed div to body so that it will stick to the same position while scrolling body. Here I am asking a little bit different question.

I have a sidebar with height more than the height of viewport and I want it to be fixed to the body. While scrolling the body, it should also scroll but once the bottom of the fixed div visible, it should not scroll along with body.

For example, the right sidebar of Facebook wall scrolls along with body and stops scrolling with body once the bottom of the right sidebar visible (fixed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is possible by placing your sidebar absolute and change that to fixed as soon as the windows scroll position passes the bottom.

The CSS:

```
#sidebar {
    height: 120%;
    width: 100px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var bottomPos = $('#sidebar').outerHeight(true) - $(window).height();
    $(window).scroll( function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > bottomPos ) {
            $('#sidebar').css({'position':'fixed','top':'auto','bottom':'0px'});
        } else {
            $('#sidebar').css({'position':'absolute','top':'0px'});
        }
    });
});
```

And [**a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/90z218z3/1/).

Comment: Hey, you should change body to height = 1000px; or sth to demonstrate the fixed effect

Comment: Your welcome! Please note that if the size of `#sidebar` is smaller than the window you should change the second line to `var bottomPos = $(window).height() - $('#sidebar').outerHeight(true);`

Answer (score 2):

Here you have three tutorials for the intended task (first results out of google with query: "fixed sidebar on scroll")

http://www.waypointarts.com/blog/2013/06/29/fixing-a-side-bar-while-scrolling-until-bottom

http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-sidebar/

http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

Here is the code for one of the approaches:

CSS

```
#page-wrap { 
  width: 600px; 
  margin: 15px auto; 
  position: relative; 
}

#sidebar { 
  width: 190px; 
  position: fixed; 
  margin-left: 410px; 
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"), 
        $window    = $(window),
        offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 15;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: here you have comment :))

Comment: thank you for you comment ... I'll call you George because your last name is unbelievably unpronounceable :) Aswer seems to be too big and with relevant resources to be a comment, imo.

Comment: can't argue with that. Updated with code from one of the example tutorials.

Comment: +1 I have up voted because your second link exactly shows what I was looking for but I accepted a simpler answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the Facebook sidebar as an example it seems that as soon as the browser scrolls vertically to a certain threshold (the top of the screen hits the top of the final ad in the sidebar) it changes the class on the sidebar.

At this point it sets the css position to fixed and sets a top style on the sidebar of -???px so that it appears at that threshold has not moved but when you scroll down it will not scroll anymore.

You can detect the offset of a particular element using the jquery scrollTop() function. http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Answer (score 0):

With absolute position (in fixed position we have to hide scroll and set scrollTop instead of top):

```js
$(document).scroll( function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height() - $('#sidebar').outerHeight();
    $('#sidebar').css('top', Math.max(0, offset));
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#content {
    height: 2000px;
    padding-right: 40%;
    background: red;
}

#sidebar {
    height: 1000px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 40%;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpune92o/)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by testing the scrollTop() against the heights of the containers.

```js
var $sidebar   = $("#sidebar"),
      $window    = $(window),
      offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
      topPadding = 50,
      calc= 0,
      max = 0;

$window.scroll(function() {
    calc = $window.scrollTop() + $sidebar.height() + offset.top;
    if(calc > $('#main').height()) {
          max = $('#main').height() - $sidebar.height();
          $sidebar.stop().css('marginTop', max);
    } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top
      });
    } else {
      $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0 
      });
    }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}

#main, #more {
    width:70%;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    height: 900px;
    float:left;
}

#more {
    background-color: red;
}
p {
    margin-top:50%;
}
#sidebar {
    width:30%;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    height: 500px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main">
        <p>Main Content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <p>Sidebar</p>
    </div>
    <div id="more">
        <p>More Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```